# How to use entity framework tool for migrations in a simple class library

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In the book of Adam Freeman and in the Microsoft documentation it's written that to create and apply migrations you must run two commands with the Entity Framework tools.

This to create a migration called Initial.

```
dotnet ef migrations add Initial
```

This to apply the migration, so that the database will be created thanks to your model.

```
dotnet ef database update
```

In the book of Alan Freeman the DbContext is declared and used directly by the asp.net core project, but since I use the multi-layer pattern in my case the DbContext is in a separate class library.

In my solution there are two projects:

- VirtualMarket.UI: it's the asp.net core project which interacts with the user
- VirtualMarket.Engine: it's a simple class library where there is the model, the repository and the DbContext class. I installed Entity Framework Core in this library.

In the book of Alan Freeman the DbContext is declared as a service in the Startup.ConfigureServices method in the asp.net core project.

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opts => opts.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:ProductConnection"]));
```

In my case in Startup.ConfigureServices I have the following line.

```
services.AddTransient<IEngine, EngineClass>();
```

The Engine class is in the project VirtualMarket.Engine.

```
public class EngineClass : IEngine
{
        public IPicturesRepository PicturesRepository { get; } = new PicturesRespository();
        public IShopsRepository ShopsRepository { get; } = new ShopsRepository();
        public IUsersRepository UsersRepository { get; } = new UsersRepository(new DataContext(GetUsersRepositoryOptions()));

        private static DbContextOptions GetUsersRepositoryOptions()
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder connStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            connStringBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;
            connStringBuilder.InitialCatalog = "VirtualMarket";
            connStringBuilder.DataSource = "(local)";

            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connStringBuilder.ConnectionString);

            return optionsBuilder.Options;
        }
}
```

The problem is that when I run the command...

```
dotnet ef migrations add Initial
```

...I get the following error

> No DbContext was found in assembly 'VirtualMarket.UI'. Ensure that
> you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither
> abstract nor generic.

I don't want the DbContext class in VirtualMarket.UI: this would break the multi-layer pattern!! Is there any (alternative) solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the "--project" and "--startup-project" arguments for the "dotnet ef migrations add" command.  In your case, "--project" would be the project with the DBContext class definition, and "--startup-project" would be the UI project that has the Startup.cs file in it.  For more information, you can see the CLI documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#common-options